# C++ - Continuously Update WxWidgets Value While Program Is Running

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am currently writing a small GUI application in C++ using WxWidgets.

I have a wxStaticText widget which has a value in it.

How can I continuously update that value as my program is running?

I have tried using the Update UI event:

```
Connect(wxEVT_UPDATE_UI, wxUpdateUIEventHandler(MyFrame::Display))
```

although this updates the value, it is not smooth i.e. the values are "blinking" in between updates, is there any way I can stop this blinking and have a continuous, smooth update?

Comment: What does the `static` mean  in `wxStaticText`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your CPU utilization?

It looks like ( as far as I can tell from the tiny fragment of code you posted ) that you are rewriting your entire display many, many times a second.  Not good!

It would be better, if you haven't already in the code you are not showing us, to ***only*** update the wxStaticText widget label and ***only*** when the value has actually changed.